# Unable to upload 70MB .Zip file

Tags: file-upload

This is the situation:

- Max-upload size is set to 100 MB
- zip isn't in the list of blocked file types

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

The error-message that is given doesn't contain any error-number of error-message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first a reboot.
Also check that no time out occurs. You can increase the time out value in the web.config.

How to achieve this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/09/04/how-to-increase-the-timeout-for-a-sharepoint-2010-website.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This may sound silly, but please make sure you have enough hard disk space on the machine where you database is located. 
If this isnt the cause of the problem, try increasing your IIS Timeout and the max request size in your web.config

Kind Regards

Comment: I did this and it didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the above, make sure the file name doesn't have any special characters in it like: & " : * ? <> # {} % ~ / \ Tab

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/06/illegal-characters-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: The file-name only contains normal characters and a _. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You must increase the max upload size both in SharePoint and in IIS.

See [Sharepoint 2007/2010: How To Increase File Upload Size Limit](http://tolgaizgi.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/sharepoint-20072010-how-to-increase-file-upload-size-limit/)

Comment: I did this but this didn't solved the problem we're having. Maybe the IIS-server should get a reboot?